# Updating Drupal core in a Acquia Dev Desktop?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

Running the latest Acquia Dev Desktop (with subscription) with Drupal 7.22 core.

I´d like to update the Drupal core to the most recent version, but after reading the documentation on Acquia that is available to unsubscribed users, I wonder if that is at all possible. Any ideas on how one would go about this?

Comment: Actually the Acquia version of Drupal is still at 7.22, so you can't update yet with our without a subscription... https://www.acquia.com/downloads

Comment: Shouldn't it be asked to them directly as a support request?

Comment: The Acquia documentation for Dev Desktop lists very clearly the steps that need to be taken to upgrade your Drupal install: https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop/upgrade. Also, if you are a subscriber, you can open a ticket with them and they will assist you.

Comment: Ah, I see I made a typo... I meant to say without subscription, sorry for the confusion. Guess I - once again - chose the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but I think there are two issues here: upgrading **Acquia Dev Desktop** itself, and upgrading the **Drupal core** of a site in Dev Desktop.

For the first, the answer above gives the link where you can find how to upgrade Dev Desktop.

For the second, Dev Desktop now comes with drush bundled in, so the easiest way to upgrade Drupal core is simply `drush @mysite pm-update`

Comment: This answer is outdated. The "pm-update" command for *drush* no longer exists.